# How to root and unlock bootloader

Tags: rooting

how do how do I root and unlock the bootloader for my Samsung Galaxy 3 S model number SCH-s968c which is the Verizon version for straight talk

Comment: This may help http://forum.xda-developers.com//showthread.php?p=47412631

Answer (score 0):

Some Samsungs have a bug in their "download mode" which will let you flash a custom recovery without even having to root or unlock the bootloader. With custom recovery you can then do whatever you want with the phone.

Comment: From my research this mo del

Comment: From my research this model does not.  Every technic I have found does not work. Apparently if the model ids made after august 2014 No one has found a way to root

Comment: Verizon models come with a locked bootloader which makes it impossible to root.

Comment: Is that for sure? Sometimes it's as simple as flashing a pre-rooted ROM. Unlocking the bootloader isn't necessary to root many devices. HOWEVER, if no root method exists, then you can't root the device.